# Вставка видео на адаптивный сайт

Tags: html, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, видео

Вопрос такой.
Необходимо сделать нечто подобное как на фото.
Есть картинка с компом, есть видео. Необходимо поместить видео поверх картинки, чтобы было ощущение, что видео идет именно на компе.

В статике, как я понимаю, это сделать довольно просто (через position: absolute), но у меня адаптивный сайт и как это сделать пока не понятно.

Заранее спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Всё то же самое, никакой разницы.

Comment: Картинку компа в блок, position: relativе;
Видео в блок картинки: position: absolute;
И манипулируйте внутри блока как хотите

Answer (score 0):

```css
.mr {
    width: 1503px;
    height: 1310px;
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/CghT2.png') no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}
.mr .robot {
    height: 220px;
    width: 300px;
    left: 545px;
    top: 196px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="mr">
    <div class="robot"><iframe width="285" height="165"   src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VS58YEcOv8o"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуй с этим поколдовать)

Answer (score 0):

Решила свой вопрос.

Код привожу ниже, а так же ссылку на jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/p45qgwc2/

Спасибо всем откликнувшимся!

```css
.notebook {
 width: 100%;
 position: relative;
}

video {
 width: 58%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 21%;  
}
```

```html
  <div class="notebook">
  <div>
    <img src="https://cdn.svyaznoy.ru/upload/iblock/c42/1.png" alt="" width="100%">
    <video autoplay="autoplay" muted loop>
      <source src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/306205121.sd.mp4?s=2b246ff476aa7d82400c3d215aabbc6fb2bf71ad&profile_id=164&oauth2_token_id=57447761">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```